# Mern Stack: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend, fetch, mern

I have a MERN stack application, Im facing this issue :

**SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data**

This is my code in the frontend

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Home = () => {
  const [workouts, setWorkouts] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchWorkouts = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("/api/workouts");
      const json = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {
        setWorkouts(json);
      }
    };

    fetchWorkouts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {workouts &&
          workouts.map((workout) => <p key={workout._id}>{workout.title}</p>)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

and this is output when I do console.log(response)

Response { type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:5173/api/workouts", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers(8), body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }
Home.jsx:9:14

my node server return a valid json (array), something like this
[{"_id":"648b46c2b757e7cd377c3fc5","title":"Bench press","reps":15,"load":0,"createdAt":"2023-06-15T17:13:38.124Z","updatedAt":"2023-06-15T17:13:38.124Z","__v":0},{"_id":"648b44d9e5cf2c8682e266b5","title":"Running","reps":1000,"load":0,"createdAt":"2023-06-15T17:05:29.790Z","updatedAt":"2023-06-15T17:05:29.790Z","__v":0},{"_id":"648b43288f596df8bbe0355f","title":"Situps","reps":70,"load":0,"createdAt":"2023-06-15T16:58:16.244Z","updatedAt":"2023-06-15T16:58:16.244Z","__v":0},{"_id":"648b428a8f596df8bbe0355c","title":"Pushups","reps":100,"load":100,"createdAt":"2023-06-15T16:55:38.480Z","updatedAt":"2023-06-15T17:37:02.415Z","__v":0}]

Can anyone help me ? thanks <3

I didnt try anything

Comment: Are you setting the request and response content-type to json?

Comment: @MuriloSchünke, yes in postman its showing this "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Answer (score 0):

I installed **cors** package in my node server

npm i cors

```
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```